# Access nested template types

Tags: c++, templates

Let's say there is a class A and MyType

```
template<typename DataType>
class MyType {
...
}

template<typename MyType>
class A {
...
}
```

When I create an instance of A with `A<MyType<int>>` how can I access the template type int inside A?

Comment: You can add `typdef` inside `MyType`, and use it in `A`.

Comment: Do you have typos? What is "A with A>" and the "type int inside A"?

Comment: Sorry for that. Fixed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another method would be like this:

```
template <typename DataType>
class MyType { ... };

template<typename X>            // template parameter name changed for clarity
class A;                        // intentionally left undefined

template<typename Y>
class A<MyType<Y>> { ...Y... }; // a specialisation

... A<MyType<int>> ...          // Y in the definition of A is int
```

This way one can only instantiate `A` with instances of `MyType`.

If there's a need to instantiate A with any templated type, one uses a bit different specialisation:

```
template<template<typename...> X, typename Y>
class A<X<Y>> { ...X<Y>... };   // a specialisation

... A<MyType<int>> ...          // X in the definition of A is MyType, Y is int
... A<OtherType<double>> ...    // X is OtherType, Y is double
```

This way, one can pass any templated type that doesn't have non-type template parameters.

Comment: What if there is another type than MyType and I want to access Y. My Intention is to access the first template type of MyType or any other type

Comment: @Gustavo added a method for this.

Answer (score 6):

Expose a [*type alias*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) to the user:

```
template<typename DataType>
class MyType {
public:
    using InnerDataType = DataType;
};

template<typename MyType>
class A {
public:
    using InnerType = MyType;
};
```

Usage:

```
using MyA = A<MyType<int>>;
static_assert(std::is_same<
    typename MyA::InnerType::InnerDataType,
    int>{});
```

[**live example on wandbox**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/1nv9R6qTlQNYE0nx)

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that this is a good case of "Do as the Standard Library does" - it's evident in containers, iterators, and just about every template in the library.